# RTABMAP with multiple ZED stereo cameras

Tags: slam, navigation, camera, multiple, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to use multiple ZED stereo cameras for the 3D mapping with RTABMAP. But I notice RTABMAP only supports single stereo camera or stereo camera+laser. Could anyone kindly give me some insights on how to do the multiple ZED cameras mapping? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274165/rtabmap-with-multiple-zed-stereo-cameras/) by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Take a look at the [multiple Kinect demo launch file](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/demo/demo_two_kinects.launch).

You would have to remap rgb/depth/camera_info of the zed cameras. Another similar [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/271347/rtabmap-with-multiple-realsense-zr300-cameras/) for ZR300 cameras.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on 2017-10-27**:
Hi Matlabbe,

Thank you so much for the insight. May I know if I would like to use the ZED odometry, how can I revise the launch file accordingly. :)

cheers

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-10-29**:
Remove `rgbd_odometry` node, then remap the zed's odom topic in rtabmap/rtabmapviz nodes: `<remap from="odom"       to="/zed_camera1/odom"/>`

**Comment by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on 2017-10-31**:
Hi
Thank you for the help. I have rewritten the launch file and run the two cameras simultaneously. I paste the details in my own "answer". I am not sure if the "static_transform_publisher" node is correctly defined since for both cameras, I use the same child_frame_id "zed_center". Is it correct?

**Comment by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on 2017-10-31**:
emm, I have tried to use the ZED odometry by removing the rgbd_odometry node and remap the "odom" as you suggested based on the same code in my own "answer". But I receive the error "TF of received depth image 0 at time 1509441479.227963s is not set!". I am not sure how to fix...

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-11-01**:
base_link ->zed_center, as you set, would put both cameras exactly superposed. You would also want to set base_frame (zed1_center and zed2_center), camera_frame and depth_frame of zed_camera.launch to something different for both cameras, otherwise you will have multiple TF having the same name